# allowing clicks on Button in ComboBoxItem when IsHitTestVisible is false

Tags: silverlight, xaml

[alt text http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/9830/combobox.png](http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/9830/combobox.png)

Setting the `IsHitTestVisible="false"` has the effect of having the whole ComboBox's drop area unresponsive to clicks. The same goes for setting to true.

With a `ComboBox` I don't have to create any storyboard to make ComboBox animation like but I found this issue.

How can one make the `ComboBoxItem` area unclickable except for the button within?

Comment: Is the objective to allow the button to be clicked but not to allow the item be selectable as the ComboBox value?

Comment: Yes you're right, Anthony, because I will put more buttons there to change the ComboBox 'textbox' (RadDatePicker like). I'm using RadComboBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should be creating a custom control that uses a popup window, that just looks like a combobox, *however you can do what you wanted*:

- Put your buttons inside a grid, inside a single RadComboBoxItem
- Set the grid background colour to 1% alpha so it is hit-test visible yet unseen
- Add a Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp event handlern to the grid
- In the handler set e.Handled to true so the mouse up is eaten

Make sure you close the combobox popup when you get your button presses.

Hope this helps.